# How to compare datasets from multiple time periods

Tags: ms-access, dataset, compare, forecast

I am working with manufacturing forecast data.  This Forecast data spans a rolling 24 month time period.  For each Forecast snapshot, identified by the Forecast Download Date (FDLDT), an Excel spread sheet is created.  The Rows are Factory(FACT), Part Numbers (PN),and Order Type (ORDTYP).  The columns are Demand Dates as Month and Year (DDT), and the field is Quantity (QTY). Every time a new forecast is created, all aspect of the data can change e.g. a rolling time period can be added or dropped, a part number can be added or dropped, and the demand quantity can change.

I need to bring the data into my Access database, query and compare at least 2 snapshots and look for the progressive changes.  I am not holding out for the ability to compare step changes for more than 2 snap shots.

Thus far, I used Excel Power Query to unpivot and flatten the data.  I am able to import the data into my table.  My fields are ID, FDLDT(DATE), FACT(TEXT), PN(TEXT), ORDTYP(TEXT), DDT(DATE as MM/YYYY), and QTY(DOUBLE).

I've been searching the web for support and have not landed on anything helpful.  I can't wrap my head around how to visually present the data let alone, develop programmatically.  If there is any examples of similar scenarios or someone with an idea of how to accomplish my task, I welcome your input.

Many thanks!